# CGFontGetGlyphBBoxes wrong result

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-graphics, core-text

I have been trying to measure glyph bounds precisely but this code prints out 916!!! The real width of this is 69.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
        CGContextRef main = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
        CGContextSetTextMatrix(main, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
        CGGlyph g;
        CGPoint p  = CGPointMake(100, 100);
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        CGFontRef font = CGFontCreateWithFontName((CFStringRef)@"Arial");
        g = CGFontGetGlyphWithGlyphName(font, CFSTR("L"));
        CGContextSetFont(main, font);
        CGContextSetTextPosition(main, 0, 0);
        CGContextSetFontSize(main, 200);
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(main, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        CGContextShowGlyphsAtPositions(main, &g, &p, 1);
        CGFontGetGlyphBBoxes(font, &g, 1, &rect);
        printf("%f", rect.size.width);
    }
```

Comment: What are you _really_ trying to do? TextKit might do it a lot more easily.

Comment: Becouse I want do render single glyphs and change them rapidly

Comment: That's not much of an explanation. What's happening here that couldn't be done with TextKit, or even NSString?

Comment: If your performance needs are so tight that basic `NSString` drawing is failing you, it seems strange that you could accept a drawing method that calls `CGFontCreateWithFontName` with the same font every time. Is the above code really substantially faster than `[NSString drawAtPoint:withAttributes:]` (with a statically defined set of attributes so you don't have to recompute font objects every time?) Or do you really need *glyphs* like ligatures? (Maybe your current example is misleading because it uses "L?") (Not to detract from LGP's answer, which I'm sure is what you need here.)

Comment: It's only simple example for my own test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `CGFontGetGlyphBBoxes`, which returns the size in *glyph space units*. To use this, you need to scale it with the units per em and the font size.

```
CGRect rect;
CGFontRef font = CGFontCreateWithFontName((CFStringRef)@"Arial");
CGFloat fontSize = 200.0;
CGGlyph g = CGFontGetGlyphWithGlyphName(font, CFSTR("L"));
CGFontGetGlyphBBoxes(font, &g, 1, &rect);
CGFloat width = rect.size.Width / CGFontGetUnitsPerEm(font) * fontSize;
```

An alternate way to do it to use `[NSFont boundingRectForCGGlyph:]`.

```
NSFont *font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:200];
NSRect rect = [font boundingRectForCGGlyph:g];
```

> **boundingRectForCGGlyph**
>   Returns the bounding rectangle for the specified glyph, scaled to the receiver’s size.

Comment: So I need to divide by  CGFontGetUnitsPerEm?

Comment: Yes, times the font size.     `CGFloat width = glyphWidth / CGFontGetUnitsPerEm(font) * 200.0;`

Comment: Also, don't forget to round up to nearest pixel if needed. :)